# Proper way to check if Web.Title is available (CSOM)?

Tags: client-object-model

We can check if Web.Title is available this way:

```
if (!_clientContext.Web.IsPropertyAvailable("Title"))
{
  _clientContext.Load(_clientContext.Web, w => w.Title);
  _clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

but is this generic, meaning that property name always can be checked by finding the corresponding string name? Can we somehow check this without passing string as a parameter?

Comment: No, this is the only way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SharePoint CSOM [ClientObject.IsPropertyAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientobject.ispropertyavailable.aspx) method accepts property name as a string only, but you could utilize the following method that accepts property as an expression:

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines if Client Object property is loaded
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="clientObject"></param>
/// <param name="property"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static bool IsPropertyAvailable<T>(T clientObject, Expression<Func<T, object>> property) where T : ClientObject
{
        var expression = (MemberExpression)property.Body;
        string propName = expression.Member.Name;
        return clientObject.IsPropertyAvailable(propName);
}
```

Usage

```
if(!IsPropertyAvailable(web, w => w.Title))
{
    context.Load(context.Web, w => w.Title);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
}
```

---

**Update**

Since both [ClientObject.IsPropertyAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientobject.ispropertyavailable(v=office.15).ASPX) and [ClientObject.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientobject.isobjectpropertyinstantiated(v=office.15).aspx) methods are used to identify whether the specified property has been retrieved or not (in first case for `scalar` properties, in the second one for `client object collection` properties), below is provided a more generic method:

```
public static class ClientObjectExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether Client Object property is loaded
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="clientObject"></param>
    /// <param name="property"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool IsPropertyAvailableOrInstantiated<T>(this T clientObject, Expression<Func<T, object>> property)
        where T : ClientObject
    {
        var expression = (MemberExpression)property.Body;
        var propName = expression.Member.Name;
        var isCollection = typeof(ClientObjectCollection).IsAssignableFrom(property.Body.Type);
        return isCollection ? clientObject.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated(propName) : clientObject.IsPropertyAvailable(propName);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{

     ctx.Load(ctx.Web, w => w.Lists, w => w.Title);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();


     if (ctx.Web.IsPropertyAvailableOrInstantiated(w => w.Title))
     {
         //...
     }

     if (ctx.Web.IsPropertyAvailableOrInstantiated(w => w.Lists))
     {
         //...
     }
}
```

Comment: this seems great :) we could also slightly modify this to create an extension method "public static bool IsPropertyAvailable<T>(this T..." so we could call it like: "if (context.Web.IsPropertyAvailable(w => w.Title))"

Comment: Good idea about extension method

Answer (score 3):

Since C# 6.0, you can use [**nameof**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) in order to avoid the extra work that comes with Reflection. The **nameof**(property) reference is converted to a string during compilation.

```
        if (!site.IsPropertyAvailable(nameof(site.Id)))
        {
            context.Load(site, s => s.Id);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```